# Bash - read a properties file and merge lines by keys

Tags: linux, bash

I have a properties file of the form:

```
group1=A,B,C
group1_count=10

# zero or more number of empty lines

group2=A,E
group2_count=1
...
...
```

I would like to read the file in a bash script and print something like: **group_name**:**group_count**:**group_items**:

```
group1:10:A,B,C
group2:1:A,E
```

Comment: Which version of bash? Can there ever be an underscore in a group name?

Comment: (To explain "which version" -- if you need to support bash versions before 4.0, I'd suggest using a different language -- even if that language is just awk; only as of 4.0 does bash support "associative arrays" -- what Go would call a `map[string]string`; before that you only have `map[int]string`, which isn't nearly so useful when you need to correlate by keys)

Comment: bash 3. no underscores in a group name

Comment: If you _do_ have associative arrays, though, the implementation should be pretty straightforward -- as in, it'd be helpful to know where you're stuck (in terms of what specific operation you don't know how to do), since otherwise this just reads as a "please implement my program for me" question.

Comment: Okay, if it's bash 3, I just _wouldn't use bash_. Let me guess, you're on Mac? As much as I hate zsh (and I do), it's a better choice than bash 3; so is ksh93 (which Apple also ships). And of course there's Python, or awk.

Comment: yes mac :) I think awk is pre-installed on macs so I can use it

Comment: Python, too, is preinstalled on Macs.

Comment: If I'm choosing Python then which version? Python 2 is preinstalled but different users can replace with python 3, right? so I can't assume all mac users will have Python 2 installed and available on their path and same for Python 3

Comment: You don't need to worry about the path. `/usr/bin/python` is _always_ Python 2 on any Mac running Catalina or Big Sur -- users literally aren't allowed to change the binary because it's on a signed filesystem -- and likewise, on Big Sur at least, `/usr/bin/python3` is Python 3. Just point the shebang at a specific version on the root filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is sorted (removing the need to group items that are presented out-of-order -- which would call for data structures bash 3 doesn't support), you can do something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
name=
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = *"#"* ]] && line=${line%%"#"*} # strip comments
  [[ $line ]] || continue # skip empty lines
  [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]+$ ]] && continue # skip lines with only whitespace
  new_name=${line%%_*}; new_name=${new_name%%=*}
  if [[ $new_name != "$name" ]]; then
    if [[ $name ]]; then
      echo "${name}:${count}:${groups}"
    fi
    name=$new_name; count=; groups=
  fi
  case $line in
    *_count=*) count=${line#*_count=} ;;
    *=*)       groups=${line#*=} ;;
  esac
done
echo "${name}:${count}:${groups}"
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/nrpfLO

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk` also:

```sh
awk -F= -v OFS=: 'NF!=2 {next} sub(/_count$/, "", $1)
{print $1, $2, grp[$1]} {grp[$1] = $2}' file

group1:10:A,B,C
group2:1:A,E
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac there should be `ed` by default.

The `script.ed`

```
g/^$/d
g/./+1s/.*=\(.*\)/ \1/
g/./;+1j\
s/^\([^=]*\)\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)$/\1\3\2/\
s/[=  ]/:/g
,p
Q
```

---

Now run

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```